# Find out the number of connections to tomcat server

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat5.5

I have a Java/Java EE web application deployed on Tomcat Server 5.5.17. I want to know the number of clients which are connected to the server. How can we find it out?

Comment: What do you mean by "connected"? Unless you "keep-alive" them, HTTP connections are not persistent.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most reliable way would be to search for `ip.addr.of.srv:port` in `netstat`. Here's the Windows based example (sorry, no Linux guru here ;) )

```
netstat -np tcp | find "12.34.56.78:80"
```

Replace `12.34.56.78` by IP where Tomcat listens on and `80` by port where Tomcat listens on.

This is actually not a programming problem, hence I voted to migrate this question to [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: I use Apache Geronimo and it displays in the web console the number of current busy threads (not sessions) so it is programmable.  For your solution, you should have netstat -np tcp | find "12.34.56.78:80" | find "ESTABLISHED" so you don't include non-established states like FIN_WAIT, SYN_SENT, etc.

Comment: count(threads) != count(connections). There may be means of a threadpool and/or threads used for other purposes (daemons, backgroundtasks, cleanup, etc). As to your netstat suggestions, this makes indeed more sense.

Comment: I accomplished this in CentOS with ````netstat -an | grep :80 | wc -l```` as described in this [article](https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/find-number-active-connections-linux-using-netstat/)

Answer (score 4):

And if you need to figure to what each connection is doing , use this on linux

```
netstat -an | grep :8080 | awk '{print $6}'
```

If there are three connections , you will see

LISTEN
TIME_WAIT
TIME_WAIT

And if you only want to count connections which are in TIME_WAIT state

```
netstat -an | grep :8080 | grep TIME_WAIT | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

See the section under [Tomcat Manager](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Session%20Statistics) for an example of counting the sessions in a webapp.

Counting the number of connections is probably a bit harder. Tomcat starts a new thread for each request coming in up to a maximum of `maxProcessors`. Beyond this number, the requests are queued up to a maximum of `acceptCount`. Requests beyond this number are refused/dropped (or crashes, I am not sure). The properties can be monitored using a JConsole: [Steps here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/monitoring.html). The specific properties mentioned above are properties of the [HTTP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html).

**EDIT 1:**

After looking through source code of CoyoteConnector and AJP Connector, there is a private property called `curProcessors` which tracks the number of processors currently in use. However, adding the curProcessors variable to the mbeans file for connectors does not seem to display the  current value in the JConsole display.

Note: The mbeans XML file that I modified was in tomcat\server\lib\catalina.jar and is in the org\apache\catalina\connector directory in the jar. Below is an example of the entry I added:

```
<attribute   name="curProcessors"
    description="the number of processors currently in use"
    type="int"/>
```

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between number of sessions and number of connections? I think I need to know the number of connections to a tomcat server.

Comment: I am quoting from the API docs-
Session - Provides a way to identify a user across more than one page request or visit to a Web site and to store information about that user. The session persists for a specified time period, across more than one <b>connection</b> or page request from the user.

Basically, a user can have 1 session and multiple connections for different requests. Or, if you consider a page which is loading different sections using AJAX requests, loading each section would create a different connection to the server while using the same session (if any).