# J2ee-threads running in tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat

How to find the number of threads running in tomcat server?

please if anybody knows the answer tell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209687/find-out-the-number-of-connections-to-tomcat-server

Comment: Answers become so much simpler if you ask your search engine how to do it using -Java-.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jconsole <process-id>` to attach the profiler to your tomcat and it will show minute level details of threads and memory.

`jps` command will show all the java processes that are running. Find the process id for tomcat and provide that in jconsole

[JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I normally upload a simple JSP to display info when I cannot use JConsole or [VVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)
In this [web](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/jsp-thread-display-example) you can find some JSP examples to do this. I normally use this one:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.PrintStream,
                 java.lang.management.ManagementFactory,
                 java.lang.management.ThreadInfo,
                 java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Quick and Dirty JSP Thread Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<%!
private static ThreadMXBean thMxBean = 
ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
private static String getTaskName(long id, String name) {
    if (name == null) {
        return Long.toString(id);
    }
    return id + " (" + name + ")<br>";
}
%><%
final int STACK_DEPTH = 20;
boolean contention = thMxBean.isThreadContentionMonitoringEnabled();
long[] threadIds = thMxBean.getAllThreadIds();

out.println("Process Thread Dump: <br/>");
out.println(threadIds.length + " active threads<br/>");
for (long tid : threadIds) {
    ThreadInfo info = thMxBean.getThreadInfo(tid, STACK_DEPTH);
    if (info == null) {
        out.println("  Inactive");
        continue;
    }
    out.println(" <br/><br/>Thread "
            + getTaskName(info.getThreadId(), info.getThreadName()));
    Thread.State state = info.getThreadState();
    out.println("  State: " + state);
    out.println("  <br/>Blocked count: " + info.getBlockedCount());
    out.println("  <br/>Waited count: " + info.getWaitedCount());
    if (contention) {
        out.println("  <br/>Blocked time: " + info.getBlockedTime());
        out.println(" <br/> Waited time: " + info.getWaitedTime());
    }
    if (state == Thread.State.WAITING) {
        out.println("  Waiting on " + info.getLockName());
    } else if (state == Thread.State.BLOCKED) {
        out.println("  Blocked on " + info.getLockName());
        out.println("  Blocked by <br/>"
                + getTaskName(info.getLockOwnerId(),
                        info.getLockOwnerName()));
    }
    out.println("  <br/>Stack: ");
    for (StackTraceElement frame : info.getStackTrace()) {
        out.println("    " + frame.toString());
    }
}%>
```

I hope this helps.